# When does value attribute get added to asp.net checkbox and how to access

Tags: html, asp.net, checkbox

Can anyone explain when the value attribute gets added to html for a asp.net checkbox. Running locally for the below checkbox the html returned has no value attribute included, deploying to a test server I get value="on". Is this dependent on the version of IIS, ASP.NET etc?

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkConfirmRevoke" runat="server" />
```

Is it possible to get to that value from within the code behind? To be clear I'm not asking how to check if the checkbox is checked. I'm asking how to get the "on" string that is assigned to the value attribute.

Thanks

Comment: "Value" only has anything in it if you specify something. Either you can do it in the asp markup, or in code-behind. Same as any other property. But you have to specify the value to use, it doesn't magically appear. e.g. `chkConfirmRevoke.Value = "WhateverYouWant"`

Comment: This is the same code run locally and then deployed to a test server. I don't think it's magic but it is happening. That's why I'm thinking it's related to versioning in some way. Even if I add it to the aspx page when running locally e.g. <asp:CheckBox ID="chkConfirmRevoke" runat="server" value="on"/> it doesn't appear in the html.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox(v=vs.110).aspx actually just looking here I can't even see a "Value" attribute mentioned for the server control. Are you talking about what is rendered to the HTML?

Comment: Yeah not included for .net but it is part of the html specification https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/checkbox

Comment: true. I can't say why it would be set to "on". Maybe some extra script in the page? There's no reason why IIS would do it. .NET version _might_ affect it, possibly, but if the app's compiled the same for both servers then that's unlikely. Very puzzling.